# Setting up a Virtualmin virtual server on same subdomain as the admin console

Tags: apache-http-server, virtualmin

Is it possible to create a virtual server on the same subdomain the admin console is on port 10000 in Virtualmin?

I have tried this, but I just get the Apache2 Debian Default Page.

For example, the admin console is on

```
https://admin.domain.com:10000
```

and the subdomain I want to create is on

```
https://admin.domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new virtual host using the same subdomain but listening on port 80.
Here's an example for a default virtualhost (key being the number of the port in the first line of the configuration file) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName admin.domain.fr
        DocumentRoot /var/www

        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You'd have to adapt it to your context of course, notably the document root and the server name.

Comment: Do you believe any further elaboration is necessary?

Comment: @oldmud0: I added an example, if that was your point. But I prefer to help people to search for themselves by giving them the keywords.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the issue because Virtualmin has already created an apache conf for admin.domain.com:80 pointing to the correct document root - however, it doesn't override Apache's default page. This must be because the hostname of the server is the same as the subdomain I'm wanting to create. All other domains and subdomains work.

Comment: Can you provide your original answer with every every virtual host related to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

On Webmin open:
Servers -> Apache Webserver -> Open the options for the desired server

From the Virtual Server options choose Edit Directives and comment out (put # in front) these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.[your-host-name]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://[your-host-name]:10000/ [R]
```

Click Save.

Then you can use admin subdomain from your application.